# Do any published Shadowrun adventures feature (non-Ghoul) Infected?

Tags: published-adventures, shadowrun

Shadowrun has a disease called Human-Metahuman Vampiric Virus. Depending on the strain of the disease, it turns humans (and some non-human) animals into different types of creatures of legend. HMHVV-I turns humans into vampires but turns elves into banshees. HMHVV-II tends to result in more feral creatures, while HMHVV-III (Kreiger-strain) turns any kind of metahuman into a ghoul.

**Do any published Shadowrun adventures for any edition feature non-Ghoul Infected as an antagonist, objective, or Mr. Johnson? If so, which ones?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sprawl Wilds** for the 5th edition has an adventure called *Manhunt*.

> The runners don't know about it until they do some legwork, but a wendigo (HMMVV-I ork) makes trouble on a farm near Seattle.

Mission summary:

> Fifteen years ago Seattle was plagued by a number of vicious animal attacks. Now these attacks seem to be on the rise again.

Answer (score 2):

I know that the Runner's Companion adventure ([On the Run](https://www.rpg.net/reviews/archive/12/12237.phtml)) has not only a vampire, but a gang of them. A major character in the entertainment business is actually a vampire.

> Elvis is a vampire.